# How to make my text not leave the screen when I shrink

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hi and thanks before hand.
I recently started learning html and CSS and I'm currently working on a website, I have a div where I'm using bootstrap containers the issue is that when I shrink the screen to the smallest option the text leaves the screen to the left and I cant figure out how to make it not to.

This is my code:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 3.125rem;
  right: 6.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

#firstsection {
  background-color: #FF5D5D;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.img1 {
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  left: 8px;
  width: 17rem;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 10%;
}

.btnposition {
  position: relative;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 7rem;
  bottom: 12.5rem;
}
```

```html
<section id="firstsection">

  <div class="container-fluid container1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 text-and-button">
        <h1>Meet your perfect skating partner</h1>
        <button type="button" class=" btn btn-primary btn-lg bg-dark btnposition btn-apple "> 
          <i class="fa-brands fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg btnposition"><i class="fab 
            `enter code here`fa-google-play">
          </i> Download</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 pa-5">
        <img class="img1" src="iphone6skate.png" alt="iphoneimg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You have too many `</div>` tags

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's not an answer, you just have a mismatched amount of `<div>` opening and `</div>` closing tags, so your HTML is invalid

Comment: Ok but how can I fix it? the site im using to learn specified that I needed divs for each element i wanted to put together. Ive only been doing this for one week so I have no experience at all.

Comment: Every div consists of an open <div> class, some content, and then a</div> tag to close it. You have one too many </div> closing tags. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are using relative positioning instead of margins/padding to position your elements?

Try removing "right: 6.8rem;" and "right: 7rem" from the h1 and .btnposition classes for starters.